# column name as parameter

Tags: asp.net, sql, select

I have some columns like text_en, text_es, text_de in a SQL table. Now I want to retrieve the value from just one column depending on the language.
So I created an sql string 
`SELECT @textfield FROM <table>` 
and in the vb code I use 
`cmd.AddWithValue("textfield", "text_" + lang)`
But sql returns the name of the column instead of the value of that column. How can I get the value?

Comment: I don't suppose you have the ability to change the table design, do you? Ideally, language would normalized into a value vs. having separate columns for languages. This allows you to add more languages later without updating the table schema, and also allows better querying, i.e. `select * from <table> where language = @language`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do

```
SELECT CASE @textfield
         WHEN 'text_en' THEN text_en
         WHEN 'text_es' THEN text_es
         WHEN 'text_de' THEN text_de
       END AS local_text
FROM TableName
```

Comment: This approach is doing the trick as well. Especially in my case because the case-when-else structure covers the fact of any non predicted lang string

Answer (score 2):

Don't pass it as a parameter, pass it as a string literal. Your sql statement should be in the form:

```
string col1name = 'somename';
string sql = 'SELECT ' + col1name + ' FROM TableName';
```

But if you have a parameter passed to the `WHERE` clause you should pass it as a parameter like what you did in your question.

**Note that:** Your query, this way is vulnerable to [***SQL Injection***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). In your case, you can pass your concatenated SQL statement to a stored procedure then use `sp_executesql`, not `EXEC()`.

Comment: @Makis - Be **very** careful doing this. It is open to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: @Oded - I updated my answer. But, what can be done other than `sp_executesql` instead of `exex()` to execute it dynamically in order to sanitize data from sql injection in this case. Prepared statements can't be used with this. What else?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal - Of course prepared statements can be used. But you can pass the column name to a _parameterized_ query that in the SQL you concatenate and execute.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use variables are column names in SQL, not like this, anyway.

You need to use dynamic SQL in order to specify column names like this.

I suggest reading [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) for a comprehensive treatment of the subject.