# SQL attribute name in parameterized query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using following function for retrieving record on choice. I gave table my column name and value and it shows the result. but the problem is, **Its not getting column name as parameter like**:

```
public List<Products> ListAllProducts(string searchOption, string searchValue)
{
   db.ClearParameters();
   db.AddParameter(db.MakeInParam("@ColumnName", DbType.String, 50, searchOption));
   db.AddParameter(db.MakeInParam("@Value", DbType.String, 50, searchValue));
   string query = @"SELECT * 
                    FROM [Products] 
                    WHERE @ColumnName LIKE '%'+@Value+'%'";

   ds = db.GetDataSet(query);
   //Rest of code but above query is not executing
}
```

but when I use query like this:

```
string query = @"SELECT * 
                 FROM [Products] 
                 WHERE "+searchOption+" LIKE '%'+@Value+'%'";
```

It runs fine and give me result. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363143/column-name-as-parameter), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092869/can-i-pass-column-name-as-input-parameter-in-sql-stored-procedure) and [this one specially](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html), but got no idea.
        Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters can be used in place of values inside expressions, and for nothing else: in particular, you cannot use parameters to denote table names, column names, sort order specifiers, or other parts of SQL statement that are not values.

Your non-parametersized query works, because `searchOption` is copied into your SQL, and becomes part of the query string.

If you need to build a query that changes conditions based on a parameter, you need to change the condition to account for all possible values of `@ColumnName`, like this

```
string query = @"SELECT * 
                FROM [Products] 
                WHERE (@ColumnName='FirstName' AND FirstName LIKE '%'+@Value+'%')
                   OR (@ColumnName='LastName' AND LastName LIKE '%'+@Value+'%')
                   OR (@ColumnName='Location' AND Location LIKE '%'+@Value+'%')";
```

or fall back on generating your query dynamically. As long as `searchOption` is not coming from user's input directly, you are safe from SQL injection attacks even though your SQL is generated dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

While Trying, I came across following option and posted in answer ,so other may get benifit of this.

```
string query = String.Format(
                             @"SELECT * 
                             FROM [Products]
                             WHERE {0} LIKE '%'+@Value+'%'", searchOption
                            );
```

So the complete function becomes:

```
public List<Products> ListAllProducts(string searchOption, string searchValue)
{
  db.ClearParameters();
  db.AddParameter(db.MakeInParam("@Value", DbType.String, 50, searchValue));
  string query = String.Format(
                               @"SELECT * 
                               FROM [Products]
                               WHERE {0} LIKE '%'+@Value+'%'", searchOption
                              );

  ds = db.GetDataSet(query);
    //Rest of code 
}
```